# When using git with github and it's https utls can one have it not ask for a password or user name - just fail?

Tags: git, github

I have a setup script which clones a bunch of sub repository folders in a build tree.  Some of them are private, and optional in the build. The script will hang when github asks for a password ( which is disabled anyway on their server and it gives an error )

I want it to just NOT do the clone and report an error but not ask for a password and hang the script.

Is there a way to do this?  If so a proper way ?
some way to check before the clone call ?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to set `GIT_ASKPASS` to some command that fails and returns nothing on stdout. In fact, you could probably force an error with just `GIT_ASKPASS=/no/such/command`

Comment: Can't you just filter the list before you try them?  That would be more efficient.

Comment: `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0`

Comment: @TimRoberts  Well I would want to filter the list of urls by which ones can be accessed by the current user.  If there is a git command or other command that can detect that it woudl work.  Exactly what I am trying to do is determine that in the script.  Trying to clone it with a graceful fail is just a way to do that.